# How can I add together two local variables from different functions?

Tags: python, function, variables, local, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a program that will calculate how much of certain ingredients will be needed to make cakes, then add the amounts together to work out how much of each ingredient is needed in total.

```
chocCupcake = int(input("How many chocolate cupcakes would you like to make? "))
lemonDrizzle = int(input("How many lemon drizzle cakes would you like to make? "))


def chocolate_cupcake():
    plainFlour = 12
    sugar = 14
    unsaltButter = 4
    freeRangeEgg = 0.1

    totalFlour = float(plainFlour * chocCupcake)
    totalSugar = float(sugar * chocCupcake)
    totalButter = float(unsaltButter * chocCupcake)
    totalEggs = float(freeRangeEgg * chocCupcake)

    print("""You will need:
"""+str(totalFlour)+""" grams of plain flour
"""+str(totalSugar)+""" grams of sugar
"""+str(totalButter)+""" grams of unsalted butter
"""+str(totalEggs)+" free range eggs ")

chocolate_cupcake()



def lemon_drizzle():
    plainFlour = 240
    sugar = 300
    unsaltButter = 80
    freeRangeEgg = 4.5

    totalFlour = float(plainFlour * lemonDrizzle)
    totalSugar = float(sugar * lemonDrizzle)
    totalButter = float(unsaltButter * lemonDrizzle)
    totalEggs = float(freeRangeEgg * lemonDrizzle)

    print("""You will need:
"""+str(totalFlour)+""" grams of plain flour
"""+str(totalSugar)+""" grams of sugar
"""+str(totalButter)+""" grams of unsalted butter
"""+str(totalEggs)+" free range eggs ")

lemon_drizzle()
```

So I need the total flour from both functions to add together, and the total sugar, and so on.

Comment: You should return them from each of the functions and add them together in a third function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways you could do this, as it's mostly a refactoring question. The simplest way, in my opinion, would be to return these ingredients as a result of each function like so:

```
def chocolate_cupcake():
    ...
    return [totalFlour, totalSugar, totalButter, totalEggs]
```

Then store this information for each function when you call it

```
chocolate_ingredients = chocolate_cupcake()
lemon_drizzle_ingredients = lemon_drizzle()
```

and afterwards you can add them up

```
print "Total Flour: " + (chocolate_ingredients[0] + lemon_drizzle_ingredients[0])
...etc
```

Just gonna add a caveat, that although way requires changing the existing code the least, it's most definitely not the best way. It's not the easiest to understand. One example is why the recipe methods would return a list of ingredients in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written the code right now - it's not possible do do that. Local variables are, well, local. They belong to the function, and don't exist outside of it.

You should approach the problem differently. Instead of storing ingredients inside the functions, you could store them outside in a data structure such as a map (I've shown only 2 ingredients):

```
ingredients = {"chocolate_cupcake": {"plainFlour": 12, "sugar": 14}, "lemon_drizzle": {"plainFlour": 240, "sugar": 300}}
```

Then getting the ingredients for a number of cakes is a simple matter of dictionary comprehension:

```
choc_ingredients = {item: num_choc * required for item, required in ingredients["chocolate_cupcake"].items()}
lemon_ingredients = {item: num_lemon * required for item, required in ingredients["lemon_drizzle"].items()}
```

And you can add them up using zip:

```
total_ingredients = {x[0][0]: x[0][1] + x[1][1] for x in zip(choc_ingredients.items(), lemon_ingredients.items())}
```

There's a lot of new things here if you're a beginner, but these methods are quite fundamental to Python, so you should definitely study them.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for object oriented design (OOP - Object Oriented Programming) with classes. The dictionary or namedtuple approach is probably the simplest and best for you project.

OOP is very powerful and good to know. I'll show you some of the more advanced things you can do with classes. You can make classes work with python operators +, -, /, * etc. http://rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Example:

```
    import collections

class Ingredients(collections.OrderedDict):
    """List of ingredients with their amounts.

    You could customize this more to force each key to have a unit.
    You could also create your own Ingredient class that has a unit and
    force every value in this dictionary to be an Ingredient with the
    __setitem__ magic method.
    """
    def __init__(self, items):
        super().__init__(sorted(items)) # sort the items

        # Remove name
        if "name" in self:
            self.pop("name")

        # Force servings as the first item
        if "servings" not in self:
            self["servings"] = 1
        self.move_to_end("servings", last=False)
    # end Constructor

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the string representation."""
        return ", ".join((key+": "+str(self[key]) for key in self))
# end class Ingredients


class Cake(object):
    """Create a cake."""
    def __init__(self, number=1):
        super().__init__()

        self.name = "Cake"
        self.servings = 1

        self.init_ingredients()

        if number > 1:
            self *= number

    def init_ingredients(self):
        """Initialize ingredients."""
        self.flour = 240
        self.sugar = 300
    # end init_ingredients

    def ingredients(self):
        """Return a copy of the ingredients."""
        # self.__dict__ contains all of the users variables
        return Ingredients(self.__dict__.items())
    # end ingredients

    def update_ingredients(self, other):
        """Update the ingredients values from a dictionary."""
        self.__dict__.update(other)
    # end update_ingredients

    def show_ingredients(self):
        ingred = str(self).replace(", ", "\n")
        print(ingred)
    # end show_ingredients

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name +", "+ str(self.ingredients())
    # end __str__

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Add the total number of ingredients. Uses + operator (mycake + 2)."""
        if not isinstance(other, Cake):
            raise TypeError

        # Add ingredients
        ingredients = self.ingredients()
        otheri = other.ingredients()
        for key in otheri:
            try:
                ingredients[key] = ingredients[key] + otheri[key]
            except KeyError:
                ingredients[key] = otheri[key]                

        # Edit the name?
        ingredients["name"] = self.name
        if other.name not in self.name:
            ingredients["name"] = self.name + " & " + other.name

        new_cake = self.__class__()
        new_cake.update_ingredients(ingredients)
        return new_cake
    # end __add__

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        """Add and store."""
        ingredients = self + other
        self.update_ingredients(ingredients) 
        return self
    # end __iadd__

    def __imul__(self, other):
        """multiply and store. Uses * operator (mycake *= 2)."""
        ingredients = self.ingredients()
        for key in ingredients:
            ingredients[key] *= other
        self.update_ingredients(ingredients)
        return self
    # end __imul__

    def __mul__(self, other):
        """Copy and return the multiplied value. Uses * operator (mycake * 2)."""
        new_cake = self.__class__()
        new_cake.update_ingredients(self.ingredients())
        new_cake *= other
        return new_cake
    # end __mul__

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        """Copy and return the multiplied value. Uses * operator (2 * mycake)."""
        return self.__mul__(other)
    # end __rmul__
# end class Cake


class ChocolateCupcake(Cake):
    """Create chocolate cupcakes."""
    def init_ingredients(self):
        """Initialize ingredients."""
        super().init_ingredients() # Cake.init_ingredients(self)
        self.name = "Chocolate Cupcakes"
        self.servings = 12
        self.flour = 12
        self.sugar = 14
        self.chocolate_chips = 8
    # end init_ingredients
# end class ChocolateCupcake


mycake = Cake()
print(mycake*2)
print(mycake)
mycake *= 3
print()
mycake.show_ingredients()

choco = ChocolateCupcake(2)
print()
choco.show_ingredients()
print()
print("Total Ingredients", mycake+choco)
print()
both = mycake + choco
both.show_ingredients()
```